# Falta um espaço entre o valor da gratificação e o título da pergunta

Tags: bug, status-pronto, layout, gratificação

Na lista de perguntas, a caixa azul com o valor da gratificação aparece colado ao título da pergunta:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No SO original há um respiro entre os dois elementos, o que dá uma aparência melhor:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É possível alterar o espaço entre esses elementos aqui também?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed and will be out in rev 1874.

---

Isso foi corrigido e estará disponível na rev 1874.

Comment: Thanks! You're really nailing those bugs today :)